# LaTeX error: Option clash for package hyperref

Tags: hyperref

I'm trying to run the code below but I receive this error: "Option clash for hyperref"
Please guide me what should I do.
Any help appreciated.
Here is the code:[image]

Answer (score 60, accepted):

`hyperref` is loaded twice:

```
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage[...]{hyperref}
```

Just remove the first loading without options.

A package can be given several times in LaTeX, however, the options of the calls *after* the first `\usepackage` must be a subset of the options present in the first `\usepackage` call, because LaTeX does not actually input the `.sty` file more than one. (Otherwise each `\newcommand`, ... would cause errors, if called more than once.)

Comment: As an aside to this, I had an issue submitting to arXiv and repaired it by moving my call to hyperref above all other package calls.

Comment: @AndrewD.King `\PassOptionsToPackage` can be used to set additional options *before* the package is actually loaded.

Comment: Seconding @AndrewD.King's comment: I just had the same problem  and was very confused about what to do. A quick Google search led me here and his comment proved to be the solution!

Comment: It worked for me. Just be sure to search for the package which gives you the Option Clash error all over your files and see that it is loaded only once.

Comment: I am currently having this issue, but I am using a template which contains hyperref twice, in the following format:
\ifpdf
    \usepackage[ pdftex, other packages ]{hyperref} 

    \DeclareGraphicsExtensions{.png, .jpg, .jpeg, .pdf, .gif} 
    \usepackage[pdftex]{graphicx}
    \pdfcompresslevel=9
    \graphicspath{{0_frontmatter/figures/PNG/}{0_frontmatter/figures/PDF/}{0_frontmatter/figures/}}
\else
    \usepackage[ dvips, other packages
                 ]{hyperref}
\fi

Comment: It doesn't work if I comment out the second one either, I still get the same error

Comment: @supercoolphysicist The code in the comment calls `hyperref`once, not twice, because the `\usepackage` commands are inside different `\if` branches. Therefore, the code is not sufficient to explain the problem. Make a new question with a full, but minimal example that causes the problem.

Answer (score 21):

**BEAMER USERS:**

Notice that `hyperref` **is loaded by default**. You do not need to add it. So remove the explicit `\usepackage[...]{hyperref}` line.

In case you want to **pass arguments** to `hyperref`, you can add them in the `\documentclass` command. For instance:

```
\documentclass[hyperref={colorlinks = true,linkcolor = blue}]{beamer}
```

Comment: Ah, nice.  I solved this by removing the `\usepackage[options]{hypperref}` call and moving the `options` to `\hypersetup{}`.

Answer (score 3):

Please **DO NOT** believe this error message on arXiv. It appears even if the PDF is successfully built. Refer to the logs at the end of the post.

**Instead,** please check the rest parts of your TeX file.

You can follow the instructions below to locate your errors in TeX.

- Create a minimal TeX file.
- Add several lines to the TeX file.
- Build a PDF after adding new lines.
- Repeat the above two steps until arXiv gives an error message.
- Try to locate the errors in the newly added lines.

Good luck.

[image: arXiv Logs]

Comment: Still relevant 09/2020. Thanks!

Comment: While I believe the commentary above matches my case, see also https://www.overleaf.com/learn/how-to/LaTeX_checklist_for_arXiv_submissions which suggests setting hyperref options separately from package loading.

Comment: In particular, you may find it useful to locate the line that says `[verbose]: We failed utterly to process the TeX file 'main.tex'` as opposed to simply `[verbose]: tex 'main.tex' failed.`