# Option clash for package url. \urlstyle

Tags: hyperref, urls, url

Here is my MWE:

```
\documentclass[oneside,mtp]{iiitg}

% To add a bookmark in the pdf you can use \pdfbookmark.  You can look up its usage
% in the hyperref package documentation
\usepackage[bookmarksnumbered,pdfpagelabels=true,plainpages=false,colorlinks=true,
linkcolor=black,citecolor=black,urlcolor=black]{hyperref}
\usepackage[hyphens]{url}
\urlstyle{rm}
```

which gives me the following error on compiling

```
Option clash for package url. \urlstyle
```

What is this error and why is it occurring?
If you want to see full template and other files you can see it [here](https://github.com/kiotie32/thesissokoeradoera).

Comment: For  far more line-breaking ability than what's afforded by `\usepackage[hyphens]{url}`, run `\usepackage{xurl}`. Oh, and the `xurl` (and the `url`) package is best loaded *before*, not after, `hyperref`.

Answer (score 7):

Since the hyperref package loads the url package without the `[hyphens]` option, you get an option clash. Just move the `\usepackage[hyphens]{url}` to above where you load hyperref.

(Looking at the url for this answer, I'd say the hyphen option seems vital.)

Answer (score 2):

My answer deals with the same error message, but in another context (the one of **Beamer** presentations). It could be of interest for people like me who had to cross-check several questions/answers to get the things right (like [that one](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/553815/117801), added to the current page).

In that context, the `hyperref` package is loaded by default, which, in turns, automatically loads the `url` one. That's why, if you want to use the `[hyphens]` option on a classic `\usepackage[hyphens]{url}` declaration, you would get that error message too.

The workaround is to directly pass the option to the `\documentclass` command, which yields it correctly to the packages that are automatically loaded, like here:

```
\documentclass[hyphens]{beamer}
```